# What are the meaning of the returned values of mahotas.features.zernike_moments

Tags: degrees, feature-descriptor, mahotas

I used this function below to calculate the zernike moments of my image.

```
mahotas.features.zernike_moments(im, radius=150, degree=8, cm={center_of_mass(im)})
```

I set degree=8 and get 25 returned values. Can someone explain to me why I got 25 values and what are they?

What is this "degree" here? Is it the radial degree or the azimuthal degree?

I have difficulties to correlate this results with the knowledge from wikipedia. For example if I set degree = 2, four values are returned. But from wikipedia, there are three polynomials with radial degree = 2 and in total 6 polynomials with radial degree <= 2. Why?

Comment: Does any one knows about zernike_moments from mahotas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually as per [code](https://github.com/luispedro/mahotas/blob/master/mahotas/features/zernike.py) degree is used just to control the loop it is not used in any calculation so it seems it can be used to denote number of order